# Why is the background of common motion capture systems black?

Tags: gui-design, color-scheme, conventions

Popular commercial MoCap systems ([Vicon](https://www.vicon.com/), [Motive](http://optitrack.com/products/motive/), etc.) tend to have black backgrounds for their workspace environment. Is there any non-trivial reason for this convention?

I'm currently working on a redesign of a system that visualizes mocap data and am wondering if I should follow suit.

Comment: Following established patterns is usually good as your users will expect things to behave/look a certain way if they have used other, similar systems. However, if you have a good reason for breaking away from an established pattern in a way that will benefit the user (improved workflow, better work environment, ease of understanding, etc) then you should do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article goes into some detail about dark and light themes.](https://uxdesign.cc/dark-or-light-ui-the-ux-influence-ca6df6aff390) It makes good points about contrast between content, controls and background. Allowing more focus to the important bits.

> Most 3D computer graphics software such as Blender and product design and prototyping tools such as UXPin, come with a dark theme option. That’s not a thoughtless decision of design. Such tools can be quite complex and intimidating with the amount of functionality options available to the user. **The dark theme can let all of those options sit in the background and not appear as intimidating, while shifting the focus to the main content area** — the mesh of a 3D object or the elements of a mobile app design.

It could also be a consideration of the users' environment, maybe motion caption guys only work at night like Batman...